# moment js how to 24 hours - current time

Tags: momentjs

I want to calculate 24 hours - current time so I did like this with moment.js

```
 moment('24:00:00').subtract(now, 'HH:mm:ss').format("HH:mm:ss")
```

but I recive

```
Invalid date
```

Help me

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like this

```
moment('24:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss')
  .subtract(moment().format("HH"), 'hours')
  .subtract(moment().format("mm"), 'minutes')
  .subtract(moment().format("ss"), 'seconds')
  .format("HH:mm:ss")
```